# looping through and merging files in folder in R

Tags: r, merge, directory, pipe

I am trying to loop through hundreds of weather data files (.nc) and merge them together.

I can load them, and merge them manually using:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4) 
library(ncdf4.helpers)
require(data.table)

#define input paths, load data, then merge

baseline_path_file <- "E:/input_data/HadOBS/tas/tas_hadukgrid_uk_1km_mon_202001-202012.nc"
baseline_path_file2 <- "E:/input_data/HadOBS/tas/tas_hadukgrid_uk_1km_mon_201901-201912.nc"

BASELINE <- setDT(as.data.frame(brick(baseline_path_file), xy = T))
BASELINE2 <- setDT(as.data.frame(brick(baseline_path_file2), xy = T))

combined <- merge(BASELINE, BASELINE2, by = c("x","y"))
```

but what I would like to do is define the list of files in a folder and merge them manually.

e.g.

```
library(fs)
files <- dir_ls("E:/input_data/HadOBS/tas") 


combined2 <- map(files, brick) %>% 
              as.data.frame %>%
              setDT %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = c("x", "y"))
```

but that obviously isn't working... I can't seem to get the piping in the right order. Any ideas how to get this right? Many thanks indeed.

Comment: can you provide a link to the sample datasets?

Comment: https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/786b3ce6be54468496a3e11ce2f2669c but you will need to register to download the data

Comment: you can register for free here: https://services.ceda.ac.uk/cedasite/register/info/

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are only using `map()` to apply `brick` to your list elements, and not also `as.data.frame()` and `setDT()`.

Lacking the data, I didn't run this code, so it might not work, but you get the idea:

```r
combined2 <- map(files, 
                 ~ .x %>% 
                   brick() %>%  
                   as.data.frame() %>%
                   setDT()
                 ) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = c("x", "y"))
```

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate that.  It is giving me the following error message: 
Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `x` and `y`.

I have worked around this by writing to blocks of code - one to first turn the .nc files into data.tables, and then a second one to join them together.